# How to keep menu in sync when user types in URL in Angular 2 router?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

Perhaps not the best title but I'm lost finding a better one. Sorry about that.

I've set up router as shown in the examples in the guides and it works as supposed to. When a menu item is clicked in the navbar, the rendering component gets routed to whatever the menu points it to and it loads accordingly.

However, I've noticed that when a user types in the URL in the browser (including the routing extension), they get to the corrected page (i.d. the router kicks in properly) **but** the menu doesn't get updated (i.e. the item that should be marked as selected if they click-browsed instead of type-browsed isn't marked).

What is a simple way to fix it?

Basically, I'd be happy with an approach where the router does something **right before or after** the component gets rendered as specified in the routing settings.

Due to a more complex design of the menu system, it won't suffice to use `routerLinkActive` as one of the comments suggested. I need to perform actual actions of business logic that hide/show menus and submenus.

*app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent, Navigator, DemoA, DemoB],
  imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(Routering), HttpModule, FormsModule],
  providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app.routes.ts*

```
export const Routering: Routes = [
  { path: "demo/a", component: DemoA },
  { path: "demo/b", component: DemoB }
];
```

Comment: `[routerLinkActive]` will handle this and u have to specify it

Comment: @Aravind Thanks, man - that's a great hint. I wasn't aware of that. However, in my particular case, it won't suffice. I have a set of menus with submenus and I have to do some business logic as the route is being set. I'd be most happy with an event firing right next to the route being rendered where I can access the route's path or something.

Comment: I didn't get your actual problem. you mean `child route is active parent should be highlighted` correct?

Comment: would using a directive on your menu items solve your problem? You could use the `ActivatedRoute` module to get the current route in the directive and do your logic there, if that fits your use-case

Comment: @Aravind Sorry for being unclear at first. I didn't realize there's a neat short-cut in most common cases, as you suggested. It's not so much a *child route* as such. It's rather a menu system where clicking on an item highlights **it** but also (in most cases) opens a submenu where an additional item can be clicked (and **then** the routing occurs). When typing in an URL, I want the proper menu to be highlighted **and** the proper submenu to be shown **and** its targeted item to be highlighted. Pfeeew... Hard to explain in words, hehe.

Comment: @NeilS Possibly. I'm still new to Angular so you're welcome to give me an elaborative hand here. How does `ActivatedRoute` fit into this? Is it an event that occurs when a routing is carried out? How do I listen to it? (At the moment I'm desperately trying to subscribe to the router's events - `NavigationEnd` is apparently a thing - but I have **no** idea if it's wise or not.)

Comment: check out https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html
You can inject it into your directive component and consume it's methods either in the constructor or another appropriate angular component method, like `ngOnInit`, or `ngOnChanges`, whichever fits your use-case best